# How do I incapacitate foes for eldritch detonator combos?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've been looking through the mage skill tree and found the following note on a lot of skills from different mage skill trees:

[image]

> Eldritch detonator ability: use on incapacitated foes for a combo

This does sound useful, but I didn't find any information on what "incapacitated" entails exactly and how I can actually incapacitate enemies.

Is incapacitated a specific status effect, or a general name for effects like stun that make enemies unable to act?

Which skills and other methods can I use to incapacitate enemies, so that I can use the mage skills to execute the combo?

Answer (score 3):

The codex has the answer to this in the tutorial section, entry 1, status effects.

> Disabled (Includes Frozen, Paralyzed, Stunned, and Asleep): The target cannot move or take any action.  This effect usually has a limited duration or an action that ends it (taking damage causes a sleeping target to wake up). Note: You can hit disabled targets with abilities marked as detonators to cause devastating combo effects.

Why this is marked as disabled instead of incapacitated I don't know, but it specifically mentions detonators for it.